# wrong MC colors when launched via xterm -e mc

Tags: linux, terminal, colors, midnight-commander

I use ini-customized color theme in Midnight Commander 4.8.

```
[Colors]
base_color=linux:normal=cyan,rgb002:input=white,cyan:inputunchanged=black,cyan:dhotnormal=red
```

When I launch xterm and then manually launch mc it works OK but when I use `xterm -e mc` I get green panels instead of dark blue.

All the environment variables are the same in both cases. Same behavior in gnome-terminal or terminator.

So what's the proper way to launch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you check that env vars are the same? Running `printenv` or something similar from `mc` is unreliable: there bashrc has been sourced after `mc` was started. Instead you should look at `/proc/XX/environ` where XX corresponds to mc's pid. You need to convert 0 bytes into newlines, e.g. (if only a single mc process is running):

```
tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/`pidof mc`/environ
```

I have a feeling that the difference will be somewhere around `$TERM` (e.g. `xterm` vs. `xterm-256color`) or `$COLORTERM`.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is exactly as you said: the shell inside MC shows TERM=xterm-256color while the MC process itself gets TERM=xterm.

Comment: You've probably already figured out a solution from here; but for reference one possibility is `xterm -e env TERM=xterm-256color mc`